# Membership Oracle (MO) for $K+\epsilon B$ given MO for $K$

Tags: complexity-theory, computational-geometry

Let $K$ be a convex compact set in $\mathbb{R}^d$. Suppose that a Membership Oracle $\mathcal{M}_{K}$ for the set $K$ is available; given a point $x\in \mathbb{R}^d$, the Oracle returns 0 if $x$ is in $K$, and 1 otherwise.

Now consider the set $W= K+\epsilon B =\{x+\epsilon y: x\in K, y \in B\}$, where $B$ is the unit Euclidean ball and $\epsilon>0$ may be assumed small $(\epsilon\ll 1)$.

Is there an efficient way of building an approximate Membership Oracle $\mathcal{M}_{W}$ for the set $W$ using calls to $\mathcal{M}_{K}$? In particular, what is the minimum number of calls to $\mathcal{M}_{K}$ required to build $\mathcal{M}_{W}$ for some tolerance error $\delta\in(0,\epsilon)$?

In particular, the output $\mathcal{M}_{W}(x)\in \{0,1\}$ of the $\delta$-approximate Oracle $\mathcal{M}_{W}$ given any input $x\in \mathbb{R}^d$ would be required to satisfy:
\begin{align}
    \min( \mathbb{I}_{\{x \in  B(W,-\delta) \}},  \mathbb{I}_{\{x \in B(W, \delta)\}}) \leq     \mathcal{M}_{W}(x) \leq \max( \mathbb{I}_{\{x \in B(W, -\delta) \}},\mathbb{I}_{\{x \in  B(W, \delta)\}}),
\end{align}
where $B(W,\delta)=W+\delta B$ and $B(W,-\delta)= \{x \in \mathbb{R}^d : \forall y \in  \delta B, \ x+y\in  W \}$

Comment: What is meant by the tolerance error $\delta$?  What property do you want $\mathcal{M}_K$ to have?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/149384/755, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4389019/14578.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: The membership $x_0 \in K + \epsilon B$ is equivalent to the distance minimization $\min_{x \in K} |x_0 - x| \le \epsilon$, which might be easier to treat.

Comment: Can this problem be phrased as: given a set $K$ with a membership oracle and a ball $B$, do $K$ and $B$ intersect? If so, I don't see how this problem can be solved at all: suppose $K$ is a single point $k$ inside the ball $B$. The oracle will only give us meaningful information if we query $k$, which has a probability of $0$.

Comment: @Discretelizard The question does not ask whether K and B intersect. I am asking, given a point $x$, can you build an Oracle that tells if $x$ is in $K+\epsilon B$ (this is the Minkowski sum of $K$ and $\epsilon B$ as defined in my question and not the intersection).

Comment: @D.W. I hope my edit clarifies things regarding the tolerance $\delta$.